# liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error Reading Migration File: Found 2 files that match mychanges.xml

Tags: java, liquibase

When i try and to start Liquibase via:

```
JdbcConnection liquibaseConnection = new JdbcConnection(connection);

Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("mychanges.xml", 
new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(),liquibaseConnection);

liquibase.update("dev");
```

When it is going to update i get this exception

```
liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error Reading Migration File: Found 2 files that match mychanges.xml
```

And is caused by:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Found 2 files that match mychanges.xml
```

This seems strange because when i look in the `war` file it just contains one mychanges.xml

Ive tried renaming it and to move it to another location.

I do not understand why it is giving me this excepton. plees help

Comment: If you have this problem with Quarkus, here is the migration script required location: /src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/db/changeLog.xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it myself. The exception thrown was not correct.
It actually meant that the file could not be found.
Very strange exception for this case.

With this i found out that my classpath was kinda broken.

Comment: How did you fixed your classpath then?

Answer (score 2):

In my case the folder path to the update sql file had non-ASCII characters in it (exp: éáű). Moving the update file into an ASCII only folder path worked.

This is with Liquibase 4.2.0 (2020-11-13 release).

[Rant]

Imagine supporting Unicode in 2020.

Liquibase team: *nah*

[/Rant]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the following reason in ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.java:

```
Enumeration<URL> resources = classLoader.getResources(path);
```

Consequently your xml must be part of the classpath, not a path in your filesystem or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Check your pom.xml .There can be extra dependency in your pom.xml or some unused  projects in your pom.xml .
Also the projects you are importing using pom have same database file names.

I solved this problem by removing extra dependency from pom.xml